# urllib2 multiple Set-Cookie headers in response

Tags: python, header, urllib2, setcookie

I am using urllib2 to interact with a website that sends back multiple Set-Cookie headers. However the response header dictionary only contains one - seems the duplicate keys are overriding each other.

Is there a way to access duplicate headers with urllib2?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to [urllib2 docs](http://docs.python.org/library/urllib2.html), the `.headers` attribute of the result URL object is an `httplib.HTTPMessage` (which appears to be undocumented, at least in the Python docs).

However,

```
help(httplib.HTTPMessage)
...

If multiple header fields with the same name occur, they are combined
according to the rules in RFC 2616 sec 4.2:

Appending each subsequent field-value to the first, each separated
by a comma. The order in which header fields with the same field-name
are received is significant to the interpretation of the combined
field value.
```

So, if you access u.headers['Set-Cookie'], you should get one Set-Cookie header with the values separated by commas.

Indeed, this appears to be the case.

```
import httplib
from StringIO import StringIO

msg = \
"""Set-Cookie: Foo
Set-Cookie: Bar
Set-Cookie: Baz

This is the message"""

msg = StringIO(msg)

msg = httplib.HTTPMessage(msg)

assert msg['Set-Cookie'] == 'Foo, Bar, Baz'
```

Comment: Rushabh: No, but for things like cookies, there are libraries that handle the RFC 2616 rules. See `Lib/cookielib`.

Answer (score 0):

`set-cookie` is different though. From RFC 6265:

> Origin servers SHOULD NOT fold multiple Set-Cookie header fields into
>      a single header field.  The usual mechanism for folding HTTP headers
>      fields (i.e., as defined in [RFC2616]) might change the semantics of
>      the Set-Cookie header field because the %x2C (",") character is used
>      by Set-Cookie in a way that conflicts with such folding.

In theory then, this looks like a bug.

Answer (score 0):

This is definitely not the case for me. I ran `Python 3.10.0`  in the browser dev tools the OCS provides these two Set-Cookie headers:

```
**set-cookie**: 
               JSESSIONID=node01v0bwkcyhmqot1a3eqp3lcvwd2600.node0; 
               Path=/; 
               Secure; 
               HttpOnly; 
               SameSite=Lax
```

```
**set-cookie**: 
               ZS-TOKEN-ID=apt688t8gfqf7r4zgkv60aii; 
               HttpOnly; 
               SameSite=Lax; 
               Path=/; 
               Secure;
               Max-Age=36000
```

In the `r.headers['Set-Cookie']` they are **NOT** combined. Only the first cookie is listed.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30660832)